# GET http://localhost:4200/src/app/ficheros/nacionalidades.json 404 (Not Found)

Tags: json, angular, http

I'm desperate.

My problem is that I write the full path to my json file (I tried different possibilities) but it returns me an error 404 (GET http://localhost:4200/src/app/ficheros/nacionalidades.json 404 (Not Found)). I was investigating before asking the question. I dont know what I'm doing wrong and I'm not an expert. I leave my code so that you see it.

The component:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Servicio1Service } from './../../services/servicio1.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-componente-hijo1',
      templateUrl: './componente-hijo1.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./componente-hijo1.component.css']
    })

    export class ComponenteHijo1Component implements OnInit {
      listaPersonas: any;
      constructor( private _servicio1service: Servicio1Service ) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this._servicio1service.getTodasPersonas().subscribe((personas) => {
          this.listaPersonas = personas;
          console.log("this.listaPersonas");
          console.log(this.listaPersonas);
        });
      }

    }
```

The service:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http } from '@angular/http';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    @Injectable()
    export class Servicio1Service {
      constructor( private _http:Http ) { }

      getTodasPersonas(){
        return this._http.get("./src/app/ficheros/nacionalidades.json").map((res) => res.json());
      }
    }
```

Structure of project:
          src-app-{components,ficheros,services}

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure your file is on `src/app/...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once tried to load a local json like you but it didn't work.
The solution was to put the json file in assets folder.
Then in your code :

```
 getTodasPersonas(){
   return this._http.get("assets/nacionalidades.json").map((res) => res.json()); 
 }
```

Hope it can solve your problem :)

Best regards